# reset the UIView when UISearchController is focused

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am facing an issue where I can see a black portion in my `UIViewController` where I have a `UISearchController`, `UICollectionView` and `UISegmentControl` because of my poor design.
I have added a `UISearchController` in `navigationbar` using following code:

```
func setupSearchBar(){

        navigationItem.searchController = taskSearchController
        taskSearchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.lightGray]

        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search Text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray])

        if let textfield = taskSearchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 1)
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
        taskSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        //navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        //taskSearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["ASSIGNED TASK","CREATED TASK"]
    }
```

after adding `UISearchController` I am adding a `UISegmentControl` and a `UICollectionView` using following code:

```
func setupView(){
        //self.view.addSubview(coverView)
        self.view.addSubview(taskSegment)

    taskSegment.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    taskSegment.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    taskSegment.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    taskSegment.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: taskSegment.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

}
```

This my initial view [image: Task Screen] which is fine.

This is how it looks when `UISearchController` is focused [image: Task Screen with black part]

Here you can see when `navigationBar` hides and `UISearchController` placed at top at that time my `UISegment` and `UIcollectionView` remains at same position so I want to move it according to change in `UISearchController`.

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It hides the navigation bar because [hideNavigationBarDuringPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618650-hidesnavigationbarduringpresenta?changes=_5) is set to true. This is intended behavior.

You either need to disable this so that the view constraints dont change during presentation or you need to amend your constraints so that the view would adjust to the height change of the navigation bar. You should be able to do this quite easily by setting a top constraint to the Safe area of the main view.

Comment: I have already set the `UISegmentControl` to the safe area of a view using auto layouts check `func setupView()`

Comment: in iOS11 the search bar (when set like `navigationItem.searchController = taskSearchController`) is hidden by default and shows when you drag downwards. so have you done something to override this? and when adding constraints programmatically you should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: the black screen is window's color which is black if i set window color to white the black screen becomes white. which solves one issue. but spacing issue is still there , I need to push CollectionView to the search bar.